# How to output java annotation's attributes and values as JSON format?

Tags: java, jackson-databind

I hava defined annotation and using it on Java Interface, my code is:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Documented
public @interface ThingPropertyDefinition {
    String identifier();
    String name() default "";
    EnumDataType dataType();
    EnumReadWrite rw();
    String description() default "";
    ConstraintDefinition constraint() default @ConstraintDefinition();
    boolean isScene() default true;
    boolean isRequired() default true;
}
```

and using the annotation on interface, my code:

```
@ThingService(name = "SmartGateway")
public interface ISmartGatewayService extends IThingService {
    //==================define properties==================
    /**
     * node
     */
    @ThingPropertyDefinition(identifier = "Nodes",
            name = "节点列表",
            description = "网关当前管理的节点列表",
            dataType = EnumDataType.STRUCT,
            rw = EnumReadWrite.READ_ONLY,
            constraint = @ConstraintDefinition(unit = EnumUnit.UNKNOWN),
            isRequired = true)
    List<ThingDeviceNode> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    //...
}
```

and using java reflection to output JSON format.

```
    Map<String, Map<String, List<Annotation>>> clazzAnnotation = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    cacheClassMap.entrySet()
            .parallelStream()
            .forEachOrdered((clazz) -> {
                List<Annotation> props = new ArrayList<>();
                List<Annotation> actions = new ArrayList<>();
                List<Annotation> events = new ArrayList<>();

                Field[] fields = clazz.getValue().getFields();
                Stream.of(fields).forEach((f) -> {
                    f.setAccessible(true);
                    Arrays.stream(f.getAnnotations()).forEach((a) -> {
                        if (a.annotationType().equals(ThingPropertyDefinition.class)) {
                            props.add(a);
                        }
                    });
                });
                Method[] methods = clazz.getValue().getMethods();
                Stream.of(methods).forEach((m) -> {
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    Arrays.stream(m.getDeclaredAnnotations()).forEach((a) -> {
                        if (a.annotationType().equals(ThingActionDefinition.class)) {
                            actions.add(a);
                        }

                        if (a.annotationType().equals(ThingEventDefinition.class)) {
                            events.add(a);
                        }
                    });
                });
                Map<String, List<Annotation>> model = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
                model.put("actions", actions);
                model.put("events", events);
                model.put("properties", props);
                clazzAnnotation.put(clazz.getKey(), model);
            });
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    //TODO!
    log.debug("{}", mapper.writeValueAsString(clazzAnnotation));
```

I use jackson mapper object to output the List , and output is not whole like this:

```
"home.gateway.ISmartGatewayService": {
  "actions": [
    {
      "required": true
    },
    {
      "required": true
    },
    {
      "required": true
    },
    {
      "required": true
    },
    {
      "required": true
    },
    {
      "required": true
    },
    {
      "required": true
    },
    {
      "required": true
    },
    {
      "required": true
    },
    {
      "required": true
    },
    {
      "required": true
    },
    {
      "required": true
    },
    {
      "required": true
    },
    {
      "required": true
    }
  ],
  "events": [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  "properties": [
    {
      "required": true,
      "scene": true
    }
  ]
},
```

how to make annotation's all attributes and values to output? I test fastjson, it works, anyone ideas?

Comment: What do you see if you take one of the Annotations and do `toString()` on it?

Comment: @MrR: I want to output as a json not a string. If i using toString() method, it will output a string like :
@cn.green26.web.common.annotation.ThingEventDefinition(name=, output=[], description=, required=false, identifier=OnBoot, level=INFO), @cn.green26.web.common.annotation.ThingEventDefinition(name=, output=[],